# why Cauchy - Goursat theorem needs the function to be analytic on the contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I can not understand  why Cauchy - Goursat theorem needs the function to be analytic on the contour. Can anyone please make me understand what is the need for this?
The following is an excerpt from Brown Churchill Complex Analysis.

[image]

I was reading the proof of Cauchy-Goursat theorem . I got stuck on this condition. I have read the proof several times . But still I could not understand the need for it.

Comment: What exactly is the Cauchy-Goursat theorem?

Comment: Can you please check it in the internet?  @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: I thought it is a very well known and basic theorem ..That's why I did not write the statement of the theorem..@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: You certainly need the function to be analytic inside the contour.  The statement is also true (by continuity) if the function is continuous on the contour + the region inside and analytic inside.

Comment: So the function needs not be analytic on the contour?  Actually I was reading Brown Churchill  (page no 144) where they clearly have mentioned that If the function is analytic on and inside any simple closed contour then......>@RobertIsrael

Comment: Can you please check my question once again?@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Being analytic on the contour is a sufficient but not a necessary condition. In fact, if $U$ is a simply connected bounded open set on which $f$ is analytic and continuous on $\bar U$, and if the boundary $\gamma$ of $U$ is a rectifiable path, then the conclusion still holds for the countour integral on $\gamma$.

Comment: I know this is a sufficient condition..But this condition has been given in the sufficient condition so this condition must have been used somewhere in the proof...I want to know where this condition has been used?@nicomezi